# bibliography are not compiling

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to compile my thesis, I am getting issues with bibliography. The bibliography is not prinited and `\citeauthor{}` and `\cite{}` generate ?? in the document. I am posting my file details here. Can some please comment what is wrong with my tex file? O am using TeXstudio

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothside]{report}
%\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lgrind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{rotating,graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\newcommand{\RomanNumeralCaps}[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % package is for justify text
\usepackage{setspace}%package for linespaceing]
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
%\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{enumitem}% bullet spacing package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{standalone}% for including tikz picture laterin document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%% Figure counter%%%%%
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{figure}{section}
%\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
%\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
%\makeatother
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=parens, labelsep=newline}
% set up labelformat and labelsep for subfigure
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens, labelsep=colon}
%\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[
%separate-uncertainty = true,
%multi-part-units = repeat
%]{siunitx}

%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{
%   a4paper,
%   total={210mm,297mm},
%   left=35mm,
%   top=45mm,
%   right=15mm,
%   bottom=30mm
%}
%%%% To create line on top 
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % Required for sorting Bibliogrpahy
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%%%%%% this end here%%%%%%%%%
\def\files{all}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
%\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thechapter}
\fancyhead[RE]{\normalsizee\selectfont\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\normalsize\selectfont\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\normalsize\selectfont\itshape\nouppercase\leftmark}
%\fancyfoot[RE,lO]{}
%\fancyhead[C]{Header}
%\fancyfoot[C]{Footer}% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.8pt}% Default \headrulewidth is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}% Default \footrulewidth is 0pt
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\italics{text}}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}
{\noindent\smash{\rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{\par}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\citeauthor}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\em}{}{}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}% use to write text mode in equation
%\usepackage[showframe=true,headheight=2cm,margin=1in,headsep=0.0pt,footskip=0.0pt]{geometry}% is used to shows margins whether geometry package working fine or not
\usepackage[headheight=25pt,top=1.6in,bottom=1.4in,right=1.5in,left=1.5in,headsep=0.8cm,footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}% is used to shows margins whether geometry package working fine or not
\usepackage{lscape} % for making page landscape
%\usepackage[rawfloats=true]{floatrow} 
%\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{slashbox}%used to put slash in latex table
\usepackage{afterpage}% removing blank space before landscape
\usepackage{adjustbox}% use to rotate caption in landscape
\usepackage{bookmark}% 08_7_19
%\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear-comp,backend=bib,natbib=True]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{Ref1.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%\clearpage
\include{Frontmatter/frontmatter}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\include{Synopsis/synopsis}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\include{contents}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
%\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2pt}%use to remove white space above and below figure
%\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}).
\include{Ch_1}
%\include{Ch_2}
%\include{Ch_3}
%\include{Ch_4}
%\include{Ch_5}
%\include{Ch_60}
%\include{Ch_7}

%\appendix
%\include{appa}
%\include{appb}
%\printbibliography
%\include{Reference}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{Ref_paper_02}
```

Comment: have you run bibtex to generate a bibliography?

Comment: Press F6 in Texstudio, wait 10 seconds. Press F11. Repeat.

Comment: By the way, it is twoside, not bothside.

Comment: Thanks David and Johannes your comment helped. I actually deleted the .aux file and pressed F6 and F11 key. My document is now showing bibliography.